# Featured image on page is not displayed with certain theme: how to debug this?

Tags: themes, post-thumbnails

If using certain theme, featured images on the content type "page" aren't displayed. Content type "posts" displays featured images with this theme. And other themes display featured images too, on both content types, posts and pages.

So only the combination "page", "featured image", "certain theme" is affected by not displaying featured image.

What could be the cause of the issue? How can I debug it?

Comment: Not all themes support featured images for all post types. I wouldn’t consider it an issue that needs debugging. Some themes just choose not to display the image for pages.

Answer (score 1):

Since your post pages have the featured image, your theme supports the featured image.

First, you need to check if there is an option for the featured image on your page settings in the page details.

In case of cannot find anything related to that, you could make some changes in the `page.php` file which prints the page frontend view.

WordPress has a certain standard to print out the featured image and can find the following function (or similar) somewhere in the `single.php` file.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Insert the missing function in the `page.php` file from the post single template.

PS: Sometimes duplicating the `single.php` file into the `page.php` would be an easier way to implement it except for the parts of only post related things such as category, tag, etc.